# select from where row x column A = row x+1 column B

Tags: mysql

#### Query

```
select from where row x column A = row x+1 column B
```

#### Data

```
Car ID | Time 1 | Time 2
1      | 5:15   | 4:12
2      | 3:13   | 5:15
3      | 6:12   | 5:15
4      | 4:12   | 2:15
```

#### Result

It needs to be the row right after. So basically row x Time 1 needs to match row (x+1) Time 2. `Car ID` determines the order.

I need it so it pulls Car 1 and Car 2.

Comment: `select * from cars c where t2 = (select t1 from cars where id < c.id order by id desc limit 1)`

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister That should be an answer - if the question is reopened.

Comment: You say it needs to return car 1 and car 2. `where row x column A = row x+1 column B` indicates return row 1. `where row x column B = row x-1 column A` would be required to return row 2. Is this what you want? If so we can improve the question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

"Self join"

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
    FROM tbl AS a
    JOIN tbl AS b  ON a.time1 = b.time2
```

And have

```
INDEX(time1),
INDEX(time2)
```